# Declaring a pointer in nasm

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a simple os in nasm and I am new to assembly. From c I am used to be able to declare pointers without reserving memory for them and moving them around as I please. How can I do this in nasm? If I declare a variable e.g. by

```
var: resb 1
```

I understand that I declare a pointer and can access the value of the variable e.g. by

```
mov eax, [var]
```

Though, I cannot move the pointer to another address by

```
mov var, 0x1234
```

then I get "invalid combination of opcode and operands". So how can I declare and move pointers in memory?

Comment: Its my understanding the bss "static variables" you're hoping to rewrite are baked directly into the resulting object file. You won't be able to dynamically change where a bss (or any other?) label points at runtime and therefore I don't believe this is possible. I could be wrong of course ... but I think you're confusing bss section labels with traditional variables in higher level languages like C.

Comment: Moving variables like that is not a thing in C either

Comment: The C equivalent of what you're trying to do is `&var = 0x1234;` You might want to put a pointer value into a register where you can modify it, or even store it in memory at a named location like `static char* global_pointer = (char*)0x1234;`

Comment: @harold This was a missunderstanding. I don't want to move the variable, but the pointer to said variable (basically leaving the value of the variable in memory behind).

Comment: @PeterCordes You got what I want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov var, 0x1234` gives you an error because `var` is not an addressing mode, `[var]` would be but, nevertheless, you'd still get an error as NASM cannot tell the size of the operation.

`mov DWORD [var], 0x1234` would do (assuming your memory model uses 32-bit near pointers).

x86 doesn't have indirect address moves, while in C you can use pointers "directly from memory" (roughly speaking), in assembly you have to first load the pointer into a register and then use that register as an address.
[See for your self at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Hw_Pyb).

```
int* bar;

int foo()
{
    return *bar;
}

------

foo():                                # @foo()
        mov     eax, dword ptr [bar]
        mov     eax, dword ptr [eax]
        ret
bar:
        .long   0
```

The deference operation takes an extra instruction, this may "looks like" as using two deferences but it is not (actually, in NASM, one could see the name of a variable as a pointer to it but lets keep things simple).

You can treat the pointer as any other variable (including copy it around) by simply copying it in a register and passing it around (the first `mov` in the example above does that).
E.g.

```
mov eax, DWORD [var]
call foo                ;Call foo with the pointer in EAX

mov DWORD [var], 0x1234 ;Change the pointer value
```

---

**Regarding reserving memory**: any variable when stored in memory occupies some space, that's what makes the program state.
`resb` is used for uninitialised data, this makes uses of the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) features to save space in the compiled binary *when on disk*.
If you are making your own OS you may not use ELF at all, thus `resb` (and similar) may simply fallback as allocating a zero-initialised var (NASM will warn about this).

You can use the stack to temporarily store your vars if they have a limited scope; this will reuse the same space there by limiting the memory footprint.
Alternatively you can use `%define` to define assembly-level symbols, these are like (but not identical at all to) C `#define`s.
For example:

```
%define MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING 0x1234

mov DWORD [MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING], 1       ;In C this is *MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING = 1;
```

This won't allocate space for `MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING` since it is just an alias for the number `0x1234`. You can think of it as C **`#define MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING ((int*)0x1234)`**.  Or like `static const int *MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING = (int*)0x1234;` with a compiler that does optimize away the actual static storage for the pointer object itself.

Note however that a level of indirection is gone thanks to the fact that the pointer value is now available as a known constant.
Of course, you can still pass it around:

```
mov eax, MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING         ;EAX = Holds the value of MY_PTR_TO_SOMETHING
mov ebx, DWORD [eax]                 ;EBX = Load a DWORD from the address 0x1234
;Store or copy the EAX register to pass the pointer around
```

---

Working with pointers can be confusing if one isn't used to the x86 addressing modes.  My advice is to read the instructions manual for `mov` and be sure to understand the difference between `mov eax, 0x1234` and `mov eax, DWORD [0x1234]`.

---

If you need a pointer you can modify at runtime, you need some storage for the pointer value; it can't be an assemble-time constant or a label address.

In C, you'd use `int *ptr;` which would reserve space for a pointer-sized object either in static storage (at global scope) or in a register (or stack space) for local scope.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer. Especially your comment on ELF helped me a lot in my understanding of what I am actually doing. Still, my original issue seems to be unresoved. I read the instructions for `mov` again. It seems to me that I correctly understood it before. But sure, I could be mistaken. Sometimes, it is hard for me to switch to another mode of thinking about something. So, in my understanding, `var db 1` does two things: - it creates a label var (containing an address in memory) and reserves one byte in memory at that address. What I want is only the first.

Comment: I can use the space in memory to store another address - but this seems to be wasteful, as I already have a pointer to an address.

Comment: So why can't I do the following: declare variable `var db 1`, store this in a register `mov bx, var`, move that to another address `add bx, 0x1234`, store this in the address (leaving the value stored in memory at var untouched) `mov var, bx`?

Comment: @PurrTurbance `var db 1` will create the *name* / *symbol* `var` that will resolve to the offset of a byte with value 1 in the binary. So `db` (and `resb`, unless you use ELF) will occupy a byte in the binary and, if loaded as a whole, also in memory. If you just want to use an address you can specify it directly: `mov DWORD [0x1234], 0x5678`. This will access the offset `0x1234` relative to `ds`. Using a `%define` you can give the constant `0x1234` a name. The assembler will  manage how the bytes are allocated in the binary but it's up to you to handle memory management.

Comment: And about the `%define` directive: can I do something like this but redefinable?

Comment: @PurrTurbance If you want it to change at runtime (I guess this is what you mean by redefinable?) you *need* a variable (i.e. space in memory). Assemblers could be written to optimise a var away but that is undesirable for low-level programming. You can redefine a symbol multiple times, with the last `%define` in scope winning over the others. You can also do `mov ebx, var / add ebx, 0x1234` but you cannot do `mov var, ebx` as I said in my answer (`var` is a constant, not a memory location like `[var]` is, you cannot store to constants).

Comment: Thanks again! I think now I've got it. I didn't really get the concept of the binary itself. So the thing I wanted to do made no sense as the address of `var` must be hardcoded into the binary for the cpu to access it. Changing var would mean changing the binary while executing it. Therefore, to get a pointer, storing addresses in `[var]` is the way to go.

Comment: @PurrTurbance Yes, pretty much :) `mov var, ebx` is just something like `mov 0x6789, ebx` in disguise, so it makes no sense. An x86 instruction cannot be used to change what the assembler translate `var` to (since x86 code is run *after* the assembler is done). Meta-programming with things like `%define` and macros allow to change the assembler behaviour but in the end storing the pointer in a var will greatly improve the readability of the code.

Comment: Ok great! One last thing, though: is it possible to do something like this this more elegantly: `mov ax, [var]`, `mov bx, [ax]`? (Basically `mov bx, [[var]]`)

Comment: @PurrTurbance Not that I'm aware of. I can't think of any general purpose registers instruction that is able to do a double indirect access.

Comment: Ok then I will just continue like that. :D. Thank you very much for your help and the time you spend to answer my questions. I really appreciate it.